# What is the datatype of Months(only months) in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a  table with a column named as "months" in postgresql."Month" column should have January, February,etc not as 1, 2,3, etc. And I need to retrieve data ordered by months. what is the datatype I should used and how can I retrieve data ordered by month?

Comment: It would be better to store the numbers and then convert them to a name when _displaying_ the data to the end user. If you store `January` you can't run your application with a non-english locale

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yup Yes that is good i tried like your suggestion but in my case i can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to save months, and not entire dates, I'd create an [enum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-enum.html):

```
CREATE TYPE month_enum AS ENUM
('January', 
 'February',
 'March', 
 'April',
 'May',
 'June',
 'July',
 'August',
 'September',
 'October',
 'November',
 'December'
);
```

Comment: @Mureinnik your answer is correct . can I change the date type(month_enum) to character? i need to transform the date to one table to other table. other table month column data type is character.

Comment: @Pirinthan you can use the `::` operator to cast it: `SELECT month_col::varchar FROM my_table`.

Answer (score 3):

It is best to save the month as an integer and show the month name at query time:

```
with months(month) as (
    select generate_series(1, 12)
)
select
    month as month_number,
    to_char(
        '1999-12-31'::date + month * interval '1 month',
        'Month'
    ) as month_name
from months
order by month_number; -- or by month_name
 month_number | month_name 
--------------+------------
            1 | January  
            2 | February 
            3 | March    
            4 | April    
            5 | May      
            6 | June     
            7 | July     
            8 | August   
            9 | September
           10 | October  
           11 | November 
           12 | December
```

To make it easy to build the query create a function returning the month name:

```
create or replace function month_name(month integer)
returns text as $$
select
    to_char(
        '1999-12-31'::date + month * interval '1 month',
        'Month'
    );
$$ language sql;
```

Now it is simply:

```
with months(month) as (
    select generate_series(1, 12)
)
select
    month as month_number,
    month_name(month)
from months
order by month_number;
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you've asked, you have a few options depending on what you need:

- If you only need Months as a static record but you don't actually need the time, you can use enum, as Mureinik answered,
- If you need the Month as part of a specific time, you could use [datetime](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Assuming you went with ENUM you can just use `SELECT * FROM "Month" ORDER BY id ASC`.

a_horse_with_no_name does have a point by saying that it might be best to use numerical values for months due to localization issues. You can make Month its own separate table for different month names in different languages, but there's probably a more effective way to do it. Alternatively, could have the number for each month and upon querying you could call the name of the month based on the number in your project like suggested. That way you can call a different name depending on localization.